# Icon-font cuts off top of icon

Tags: css, clipping, icon-fonts

I'm rather new to icon-fonts in CSS and now ran into the following Problem: 
I have several boxes containing an Icon. Sadly the upper part of the icon get's cropped off.

I found out, that the icon-font I'm using is adding a ::after-pesudo-element which is slightly offset to the original element and that causes the part that is cut off. (See Screenshots)

(The Icon-Font I'm using is http://linea.io)

[image: Element]
[image: ::before Pseudo Element]

I inverstigated furhter and realized that this only occured due to the fact that I have the following CSS on the Icon:

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
```

If I remove this, the Icon-Color will become black and be shown whole.

I don't know if this is due to a bug in my CSS since I couldn't find anything on the web.

But I removed almost all of my personal CSS and the bug still occured.

Comment: Post some more code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those don't look like CSS fonts, they're simply SVGs. That off set error you see tends to happen when **the viewBox, height, or width** of the SVG isn't correct. If you still need to use them you should inline them, just copy and paste the SVG code.

Taken from the link you posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <circle fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="32" cy="22" r="6"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M53,22.735C52.948,10.73,43.599,1,32,1
        s-21,9.73-21,21.735C11,38.271,31.965,63,31.965,63S53.069,38.271,53,22.735z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

If you prefer to use a real CSS icon library, I'd recommend using something a bit a more tested such as [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/). But these are a dime a dozen and if you Google you could potentially find something you like.